# Smoothing a discrete data set

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, smoothing

I am attempting to a smooth this data set and produce a single representative curve with error bars. The method to acquire the data points was discretized with a fairly coarse step. I do not have much programming experience but am trying to learn. I read that a Gaussian filter might be a good option. Any help would be appreciated. [image: Optical dilatometer data for shrinkage of a ceramic pellet]

Here is an example data set:

```
Time (min)  Non-Normalized Shrinkage    Normalized Shrinkage
200 93  1.021978022
202 92  1.010989011
204 92  1.010989011
206 92  1.010989011
208 92  1.010989011
210 92  1.010989011
212 91  1
214 90  0.989010989
216 90  0.989010989
218 90  0.989010989
220 88  0.967032967
222 88  0.967032967
224 87  0.956043956
226 86  0.945054945
228 86  0.945054945
230 86  0.945054945
232 86  0.945054945
234 86  0.945054945
236 85  0.934065934
238 84  0.923076923
240 83  0.912087912
242 83  0.912087912
244 83  0.912087912
246 82  0.901098901
248 83  0.912087912
250 82  0.901098901
252 81  0.89010989
254 81  0.89010989
256 82  0.901098901
258 82  0.901098901
260 79  0.868131868
262 80  0.879120879
264 80  0.879120879
```

I found this code snippet online somewhere but I do not know how to implement it or whether it is even what I'm looking for.

```
def smoothListGaussian(list,degree=5):  

window=degree*2-1  

weight=numpy.array([1.0]*window)  

weightGauss=[]  

for i in range(window):  

    i=i-degree+1  

    frac=i/float(window)  

    gauss=1/(numpy.exp((4*(frac))**2))  

    weightGauss.append(gauss)  

weight=numpy.array(weightGauss)*weight  

smoothed=[0.0]*(len(list)-window)  

for i in range(len(smoothed)):  

    smoothed[i]=sum(numpy.array(list[i:i+window])*weight)/sum(weight)  

return smoothed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you'd use a library for this, rather than implementing it yourself.

I'm going to use `scipy.ndimage` for this instead of `scipy.signal`.  If you've had a signal processing class, you'd probably find the `scipy.signal` approach more intuitive, but if you haven't it will likely seem confusing.  `scipy.ndimage` provides a straight-forward, one-function-call `gaussian_filter`, as opposed to having to understand a few more signal processing conventions.

Here's a quick example, using the data you posted in your question.  This assumes that your data is regularly sampled (it is: every 2 units in time).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage

time, _, shrinkage = np.loadtxt('discrete_data.txt', skiprows=1).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time, shrinkage, 'ro')
ax.plot(time, scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(shrinkage, 3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Most of this is fairly straight-forward, but you might notice the "magical" value of `3` that I've specified in `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(shrinkage, 3)`.  That's the `sigma` parameter of the gaussian function in samples.  Because your data is sampled every 2 units in time, that's a `sigma` of 6 units.

The `sigma` parameter is exactly analogous to the standard deviation in a "bell curve" normal distribution.  The larger you make it, the broader the gaussian function will be, and the smoother your curve will be.  By trial and error, a value of 3 seems about right for this particular dataset, but you should experiment and see what you think looks best.

One more final note: There are a lot of different ways to approach this problem.  A gaussian filter is a reasonable solution, but there are many, many others.  If the exact result is very important, you should probably compare several methods and see which works best for your particular dataset.

---

In your comment, you asked about saving the smoothed data to a file instead of plotting it.  Here's a quick example of one way you might go about that:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

time, _, shrinkage = np.loadtxt('discrete_data.txt', skiprows=1).T
smoothed = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(shrinkage, 3)

np.savetxt('smoothed_data.txt', np.c_[time, smoothed])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will attempt to implement this. The exact solution doesn't matter, it's more for presentation purposes. I have multiple curves from different samples and I'm going to be plotting them one on top of the other.

Comment: Sadly I'm having some difficulties with the matplotlib.pyplot library. `ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot` I tried changing the preamble to point to where matplotlib is installed but that didn't seem to work. It would actually be more beneficial to just get a plot of the gaussian datapoints out that I can then plot. How would I do that?

Comment: @SeattleFreezer - How did you install matplotlib?  Is it possible that you have more than one python executable installed, and you installed matplotlib for one but not the other?

Comment: I installed matplotlib with `easy_install matplolib` That is absolutely possible. I have a mac and over the past year I've been messing around with different things in python. I would like a clean installation but from what I've read I could mess things up pretty easily if I don't do it properly.

Comment: What's presumably happening is that `easy_install` is pointing to one python executable and you're calling another one with you run your script.  Check the output of `which python`, and call the full path of the python executable that you installed matplotlib with (it won't be what `which python` outputs).  For example, if you're using Anaconda, and you installed it in your home directory, you might call `$HOME/anaconda/bin/python`.

Comment: Calling `which python` give me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. I'm not sure what you mean by calling the full path of the executable that I install matplotlib with. Again I'm really a complete novice.

Comment: I hope you don't mind one more question. I'm not trying to apply this to a large txt file where each column is a shrinkage curve like shown earlier. I would ideally like to output a single spreadsheet with each column being a different gaussian. I tried a for loop but I don't know how to make the 'np.savetext' command write to subsequent columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is finite, I would consider looking into Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) with a radial basis function.  This would achieve a similar result to smoothing the function with a gaussian filter, but has two important benefits:

1. It can automatically select the "magic" standard deviation of the filter, meaning that the output estimate will optimally fit your data.
2. It will provide you with an estimate of how confident it is that its output fits your data - give you optimal error bars.

Here is a example of GPR being used to estimate a sine wave:
[image]

If you think this could solve your problem, I'd recommend looking into the GPy library in Python: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/index.ipynb